# Not Able to stop Mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to stop mysql inorder to start it in rescue mode to retrieve my mysql password but its showing my me an error message and won't stop.

```
service mysql stop
```

OUTPUT:

> stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call",
>   sender=":1.131" (uid=1000 pid=7640 comm="stop mysql ")
>   interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error
>   name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart"
>   (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

output of

etc/init.d/mysql stop

> Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the
>   service(8) utility, e.g. service mysql stop
>
> Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
>   Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) utility, e.g. stop mysql
>   stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call",
>   sender=":1.129" (uid=1000 pid=7246 comm="stop mysql ")
>   interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error
>   name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart"
>   (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init") subhransu@subhransu-Inspiron-1545:~$
>   service mysql stop stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules;
>   type="method_call", sender=":1.130" (uid=1000 pid=7400 comm="stop
>   mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error
>   name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart"
>   (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

Comment: Do you run that command as root?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

You have to be root to start and stop mysql server.

If you are not root, you must be a sudo-able user, you must use the command sudo and you must know your sudo-password.